# Is it constructor overloading?

Tags: scala

I am pretty new in Scala encounter weird code snippet:

```
class EndpointMapper[A](m: Method, e: Endpoint[A]) extends Endpoint[A] { self =>

  /**
   * Maps this endpoint to either `A => Output[B]` or `A => Future[Output[B]]`.
   */
  final def apply(mapper: Mapper[A]): Endpoint[mapper.Out] = mapper(self)

  final def apply(input: Input): Endpoint.Result[A] =
    if (input.request.method == m) e(input)
    else EndpointResult.Skipped

  final override def toString: String = s"${ m.toString.toUpperCase } /${ e.toString }"
}
```

It is a class, so I can create an instance of it.
What about `apply` method?

Can I use `EndpointMapper(mapper)` like a function that would call the `apply` method?

How to differ between two apply's or how the compiler knows, which `apply` should he call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `EndPointWrapper(mapper)` - for that `apply` would have to be defined on the companion object instead of the class. What you can do is call `epw(mapper)`, where `epw` is an instance of `EndPointWrapper`.

> How to differ between two apply's or how the compiler knows, which apply should he call?

It knows which version of `apply` to call based on the type of the argument, just like with any other overloaded method.